# Get UUID from querystring Play framework

Tags: java, playframework, query-string, uuid

I have a endpoint on Java Play framework

```
GET /book   controllers.getBook(id: java.util.UUID)

public Result getBook(UUID id) {
  Book book = bookDao.getById(uid);
  if (book != null) {
    return ok(Json.toJson(book));
  }uid
  return notFound("book not found with id=" + id.toString());
}
```

and the example link is:
http://localhost:9000/book?id=935e20a4-563c-459b-a4c3-cd838cb9cfb6

I'm sure **935e20a4-563c-459b-a4c3-cd838cb9cfb6** is the UUID

when I run I get the error:
For request

> 'GET /book?id=935e20a4-563c-459b-a4c3-cd838cb9cfb6' [Cannot parse
>   parameter id as UUID: Invalid UUID string: id]

could you help me? and why it error.
Thank you

Comment: Your code runs fine on my machine. Which version of Play are you using?

Comment: thank you man, I dont know but now is worked :s

Comment: It happens to me too! But it's strange cause it does not happen all the time. Looks like it's random. 
"Cannot parse parameter id as UUID: Invalid UUID string: edit"
How did you solve it?

Comment: I didn't edit anything. so I can't help you